# How to replace a word in the for command in batch?

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, replace

How to replace words of a string in a for command?
i try that but it doesn't work:

```
for %%i in (*.*) do move  %%i "%%i:_OFF="
for %%i in (*.*) do move  %%i "%:_OFF=%i"
for %%i in (*.*) do move  %%i "%%i%:_OFF=%"
```

How to remove the  `_OFF` like `%i:_OFF=%`.

input `path/file1.ext_OFF`

input `path/file2.ext2_OFF`

output `path/file1.ext`

output `path/file2.ext2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%i in (*.*) do call:InnerLoop %%i
goto end

:InnerLoop
set x=%*
::below code demos the result
echo.
echo.%x%
echo.%x:_OFF=%
::below code would execute it
move "%x%" "%x:_OFF=%"
goto :eof

:end
```